# Inheriting two interfaces with Signals and Slots in QT5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, multiple-inheritance

I am currently trying to inherit from two interfaces.
The first one defines all the Signals, the second one all the corresponding Slots, which will be used to show the results of the function calls of the signals.

```
// Like the input of the System
class A : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Signals : 
        void signalA();
        ....
        void signalN();
};
```

```
// The output of the System
class B : public QObject 
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public slots:
        virtual void slotA();
        ...
        virtual void slotN();
};
```

In the End i need multiple classes inheriting Class A or Class B 
but it should also be possible to inherit A and B like:

```
// Can be used as Input and Output at the same time for example a GUI
class C : public A, public B // will not work
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public slots:
        void slotA() override;
        ...
        void slotN() override;
};
```

So Class C should implement the slots but also be able to emit the signals from class A.

In my Main i would create two QLists with all the "Inputs" (Classes inheriting A) and all the "Outputs" (Classes inheriting B).
The Lists are given to a Controller who connects all the Input-Signals to the Slots processing them, 
and all results from that processing to the Output-Slots.
Therefor C should be added to both Lists as it can be used as an Input and Output.

It would look like that:

```
int main()
{
 QList<A*> inputs;
 QList<B*> outputs;
 C* c = new C();
 inputs.append(c);
 outputs.append(c);

 Controller* controll = new Controller(inputs, outputs);
 ...
}
```

But i can't inherit both Classes because i would inherit QObject twice.
On the other hand i can not make the Interfaces without QObject, because i would not be able to use the Classes only inheriting one of the Interfaces as one of them would be missing QObject.

Creating a third Interface and copying all Signals from A and the Slots from B would be possible but is not really what i want.

So is there any workaround that i could try to make this work ?

Comment: I would rethink the architecture you mentioned. Qt signals/slots are usually used in contexts where your signal is connected to multiple slots in multiple receiver QObjects (i.e. one can think of this as a variant of the observer pattern). If this is not the case, you might be better off injecting your "single observer" to the observable via the constructor or any other means. Anyway, a workaround if you are sure that you are not really misusing Qt's signals/slots would be using composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: In other words, class C would contain a class A object and class B object and manage their relationship together. You might also want to expose the objects to the public interface of the class.

Comment: @Mike I don't really think that i am "misusing" Qt Signal/Slot system.  
But i don't think that composition would help in that situation.  

As far as i know i would not be able to add them to the QList if the relation of my class is not a "is a"-relation but instead a "has a"-relation.  

I think i know what you mean and this will probably be the solution i will choose at the end, but i am still curious if there may be a way to solve it like this, because it is working just fine with multiple classes which inherit just one of the interfaces.  
Thank you anyway

Comment: Well, I just wanted to point out a common mistake :)
Sure, this won't work if you want polymorphism too. I would say that you have two options: 1) Don't use Qt's signals/slots and replace that with your own "notification mechanism". In this case, you can use virtual inheritance to solve the diamond problem  you mentioned. 2) Use composition instead of inheritance as I mentioned in my previous comment. You might be able to mix the two approaches (maybe?) if your system is large and you are able to further break down the responsibilities...

Comment: To elaborate a bit on the mixed approach I mentioned in the end: I mean, have a "mix-in" base class that hosts the common functionality (but does not  inherit from QObject), and then add signals/slots in subclasses that inherit from it and QObject. I am not sure however if this is applicable to your case, but it is an alternative to consider in my opinion...

Comment: Assuming you're using Qt5 it might be possible to achieve what you want *without* class `B` needing to inherit from `QObject` -- slots are just normal member functions so no need for `Q_OBJECT`/`moc` etc.  Can you provide some more info regarding the `Controller` class -- what exactly does it do with `inputs` and `outputs`?  Is threading involved or can we assume all signal/slot connections can be `Qt::DirectConnection`?

Comment: @G.M. Just removing QObject did not work for me, but i found a way to use `Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE` and `Q_INTERFACES` to make it work by casting the pointers of the derived classes to QObject pointers (`dynamic_cast`) and using the old SIGNAL SLOT connection. Afterwards i was able to leave out QObject in the Interfaces. So thanks for the info